# PCIe ordering rules and x86, how are they compatible?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers, pci-e

PCIe specs express clearly what are the ordering rules.

- A Posted Request must not pass another Posted Request
- A Posted Request must be able to pass Non-Posted Requests to avoid deadlocks

It means any writes can be executed before an earlier read.
This rule seems to break the x86 ordering rules that are strongly ordered.

What do I miss?

Reference to the PCIe specs:

[image]

> The second transaction (row) must be allowed to pass the first (column) to avoid deadlock.

Comment: Reference added. Wording is pretty clear `must be allowed to pass`, means `writes must be allowed to pass reads`.

Comment: The x86 memory ordering rules, in this context, determine the order in which loads and stores hit the memory bus and thus reach the PCIe controller.  Presumably, the controller can reorder them further before sending to the device.

Comment: Reference? It shouldn't, no controller is allowed to reorder memory accesses, only the CPU can, and is based on memory barriers. If anything after the CPU reorders instructions, the sequence of a particular program is changed, changing what the application does.

Answer (score 4):

PCIe agents can do Posted vs Non-Posted reordering for two main reasons:

1. Avoid deadlocks
2. Improve resource utilization (bandwidth, receiving buffers, and so on)

The second bullet is straightforward to understand: an NVMe may let a write pass a read if the two are to different addresses and latching/caching the write is faster/easier.
Of course, in general, reordering writes and reads is *not possible*, not even for system memory, let alone when accessing IO devices where even reads can have side effects (e.g. clearing status bits).

However, devices (more than switches, which must obey the Relaxed Order bit) are free to implement their own optimizations.

Switches and bridges may find it necessary to reorder transactions when they do complex mappings. This brings us to the first bullet above: deadlocks.
I've never really dug into this topic, so this is all handwaved.
Some devices may need to perform other transactions before they can handle (i.e. complete) the transaction they just received. The PCIe specifications give these examples:

- Bridges to complex protocols that require state to be save/restored to/from host memory, i.e.,
  PCI Express to Infiniband bridges.
- Messaging engines that must do address translation based upon page tables stored in host
  memory.
- UMA graphics devices that store their frame buffer in host memory.

For example, an MMIO may read its page table entries from a secure memory area hosted on an ad-hoc PCIe device. So upon receiving a downstream memory read the MMIO issues another read request to the secure memory. In turn, this secure memory device may need to generate an MSI (due to a missing entry, for example) and thus go back through the MMIO which is still waiting for its request to finish and thus deadlocking.

This is a contrived example for sure, but the general idea is that PCIe topology and functionality are complex enough to generate deadlocks and the PCIe ordering rules allow solving some of these deadlocks.
Surely the protocol semantic holds, if you read from address X and then write to address X then you can be sure that any agent will obey "as-if" causality.

Regarding the x86 memory model, it has nothing to do with this. At least directly. The x86 memory model determines the order and the type of requests that arrive at the Root Complex. It's your responsibility to make sure these requests arrive in the correct order (e.g. by using UC MMIO) or not (e.g. by using WC MMIO).
Once they are at the root complex, the PCIe protocol will follow its rule.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is unnecessary long describing unrelated aspects of the specs. You say x86 is unrelated, but you say it's up to the Root Complex. If the RC reorders the accesses, x86 isn't followed anymore. What you could say is that in x86, a store will never be sent to the RC until the CPU has received the data.

Comment: You are welcome @Alexis but I don't understand your point. The x86 memory model regards the x86 cores. Once a UC store exits a core, it goes into the Ring buffer and then to its destination (e.g. the iMC or the RC in the System Agent). The PCIe reordering is "memory model" on top of the x86 memory model if that's what you want to be told. But I think that's pretty obvious that PCIe agents can't reorder loads/stores execution in the cores...  and that, as stated, a PCIe agent may have reasons to reorder the **requests** it receives.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that as Nate specified in the comments, a controller of a protocol is allowed to perform re-ordering as long it doesn't violate the protocol (though it actually makes the issue you've presented more severe).

For example, a DDR controller is allowed to re-order requests to get more performance from the DDR:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683841/17-0/command-and-data-reordering.html

And there is such capability also in PCIe on the RX path:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683093/15-1/receive-buffer-reordering.html

And the same goes for other protocols, for example AXI.

An interconnect switch/bridge/convertor/etc. is usually allowed to do whatever it wants, as long it meets the interconnect rules, so the x86 rules are not interesting to the PCIe interconnect.

The answer to your question is that it's the CPU's responsibility, as the PCIe interconnect agent, to make sure the PCIe interconnect will not violate the needed ordering model.

One way to enforce it is to perform HW fencing.
For example, let's say I want an ordering model where posted requests never pass non-posted, when they are to the same address.
But I am using an interconnect where it can happen, such as PCIe.

Then it's my responsibility, as the interconnect agent, that if I identify that I have a posted request following a non-posted to the same address, to issue the non-posted, wait for the non-posted to be completed, and only then issue the posted, safely, to the same address (this is possible since non-posted requests have a completion).

Those kind of mechanisms are common different HW NoCs. For example it's very common in fabrics like AXI4, which have very relaxed ordering between reads and writes.

It can be implemented in numerous places:

- It may exist in the CPU itself
- It may exist in the cache
- It may exist right before the PCIe controller
- If you (as a HW vendor) implement the PCIe controller by yourself, then it can also exist there.

The HW can also be hinted to protect this issue by SW barriers commands.

This is really architecture dependent.

AFAIK, in x86 this HW mechanism exists in the memory sub-system, which re-orders the memory requests.

https://coffeebeforearch.github.io/2020/11/29/hardware-memory-ordering.html

Comment: The case of the DDR is different because it's an endpoint and DDR is prefetchable unlike registers which a rd/wr can clear flags and so on. The AMBA protocol has barrier transactions.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree on that. I just wanted to make a point that once you got to the "interconnect domain" - the interconnect can do whatever it wants, as long it meets the interconnect rules. including re-ordering of transactions.

So this very long answer of mine basically sums up to "the CPU must wait for non-posted transaction to end before issuing the posted one, if a strict order is required between the two".

Answer (score 0):

After some thoughts, here is my assumption:

A load reaching the Root Complex will be blocked until it receives the data before submitting new instructions, potentially stores.
Therefore with x86, the PCIe will never see a store after an unfinished load.

Same for multi-threading, a store can appear right after a load if both are sent from a different core, and the store can be reordered first. Nevertheless, it's up to the SW developer to use proper locking mechanism to avoid this situation.

In the end, PCIe specs don't contradict with the x86 ordering model.